# Delete method of Range failed

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a 'database' in excel vba, but when I try to delete an row out of my source, which is selected by ID number and press delete it gets stuck at `Rows(Y).Delete Shift:=xlUp`, I am not sure why, it did work before, but somehow I broke something?

All data is displayed in the listbox. The error message is `Run-Time error '1004': Delete method of Range failed`

[image: The Generic look of it all]

```
Dim X As Long
Dim Y As Long

X = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Y = 2 To X

If Sheet1.Cells(Y, 1).Value = Searchtxt.Text Then

Rows(Y).Delete Shift:=xlUp

End If
Next Y

Unload Me
MyUserForm.show

End Sub
```

I also leave this link to the google drive:

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_VBhBYqNal_U5YphICTH9UQsulEajOrM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Rows()` assumes that you want the `ActiveSheet`.  You're going to run into problems if you don't specify which `Sheet`, as the `ActiveSheet` could be different then the one that your database is on.  Always be specific, use:

   `Sheet1.Rows(Y).Delete Shift:=xlUp`
2. If you allow multiple lines to be selected, as you start to delete rows, your data shifts up and you end up skipping the next row as you you delete one.  The easy way to fix it is to count backwards, so that you're not affecting the data as you delete.

   `For Y = X To 2 Step -1`

Or even better, **for speed**, clump it into a range and delete it all at one in the end.  It doesn't matter if you count up or down using this method.

```
Dim DeleteRows as Range
For Y = 2 To X
    If Sheet1.Cells(Y, 1).Value = Searchtxt.Text Then 
        Set DeleteRows = MakeUnion(DeleteRows,Sheet1.Rows(Y))
    End IF
Next Y
If Not DeleteRows is Nothing Then DeleteRows.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Where I used the following function to keep the code looking clean.

```
Public Function MakeUnion(Arg1 As Range, Arg2 As Range) As Range
    If Arg1 Is Nothing Then
        Set MakeUnion = Arg2
    ElseIf Arg2 Is Nothing Then
        Set MakeUnion = Arg1
    Else
        Set MakeUnion = Union(Arg1, Arg2)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, and even more thanks to the extra information, it good to know that there a many other methods that also work.